# How to capitalize first letter of each word except certain words ("and", "but", "of")?

Tags: c, cs50

Input given is: `the lord of the rings`
Output expected is: `The Lord of the Rings`
But what I get is: `The Lord ofof thethe Rings`

CODE:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  string s = GetString();
  //to print an upper case char 
  printf("%c", toupper(s[0]));


  for (int i = 1, n = strlen(s); i <n; i++)
  {
    //not to capitalize and but of
    if (isspace(s[i]))
    {
        if (s[i + 1] == 't' && s[i + 2] == 'h' && s[i + 3] == 'e') {
            printf("%c%c%c%c", s[i], s[i + 1], s[i+2], s[i+3]);
        } else if (s[i + 1] == 'a' && s[i + 2] == 'n' && s[i + 3] == 'd') {
            printf("%c%c%c%c", s[i], s[i + 1], s[i+2], s[i+3]);
        } else if (s[i + 1] == 'b' && s[i + 2] == 'u' && s[i + 3] == 't') {
            printf("%c%c%c%c", s[i], s[i + 1], s[i+2], s[i+3]);
        } else if (s[i + 1] == 'o' && s[i + 2] == 'f') {
            printf("%c%c%c", s[i], s[i + 1], s[i+2]);
        } else { //capitalize rest of the code:
            printf("%c%c", s[i], toupper(s[i + 1]));
            i++;
        }            
    } else {
        if(   (s[i] == 't' && s[i + 1] == 'h' && s[i + 2] == 'e') 
           || (s[i] == 'a' && s[i + 1] == 'n' && s[i + 2] == 'd') 
           || (s[i] == 'b' && s[i + 1] == 'u' && s[i + 2] == 't') 
           || (s[i] == 'o' && s[i + 1] == 'f' ) )
            continue;          
        else
            printf("%c",s[i]);           
     }
   }
}
```

Please help me to solve it.

Comment: High time to use a debugger.

Comment: This code would be much better with a variant of `strcmp()` instead of checking each character separately.

Answer (score 2):

In each `if` clause, after you skip over a stop word, you need to adjust the index by the length of the word, e.g.:

```
if (s[i + 1] == 't' && s[i + 2] == 'h' && s[i + 3] == 'e') {
   printf("%c%c%c%c", s[i], s[i + 1], s[i+2], s[i+3]);
   i += 3; // Skip the next 3 positions
}
```

This still does not solve the problem of not capitalizing the longer words that "look like" stop words (e.g., *android*, *butter* or *offset*).

Answer (score 2):

I would consider learning about the `strtok()` function. You can use this to break your line into individual words. Then if you have an array containing the words that should not be capitalized, each word can be checked against this list using `strcmp()`, and capitalized if appropriate, before adding it to an array containing the capitalized line. The code below does this, and always capitalizes the first word. Note that `skip_list[]` contains a `NULL` pointer after the last word; this is used in iterating over the list. Also note that the array `title[]`, which is used to store the capitalized result, is allocated so that it is long enough to hold the `input` string, including the `NUL` terminator. Further, `title` is first defined to be an empty string so that the first `word` token may be safely concatenated with it using `strcat()`.

This approach could be improved by writing an `upcase()` function that upcases the first alphabetic character of a word, and downcases the remaining characters, and a `downcase()` function that downcases all characters in a word. Instead of blindly upcasing only the first character, this would allow better handling of messy inputs, e.g., `"tHe lorD oF The rINgs"`.

One final note: the function `strtok()` will modify `input` by writing `'\0'` characters into it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define MAX_SKIP  100

bool in_list(const char *word, const char **list);

int main(void)
{
    const char *skip_words[MAX_SKIP] = { "and", "but", "of", "the", NULL };
    char input[] = "the lord of the rings";
    size_t title_sz = strlen(input) + 1;
    char title[title_sz];
    char *word;

    title[0] = '\0';
    word = strtok(input, " ");
    word[0] = toupper(word[0]);
    strcat(title, word);
    while ((word = strtok(NULL, " "))) {
        if (!in_list(word, skip_words)) {
            word[0] = toupper(word[0]);
        }
        strcat(title, " ");
        strcat(title, word);
    }

    puts(title);

    return 0;
}

bool in_list(const char *word, const char **list)
{
    while (*list != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(word, *list) == 0) {
            break;
        }
        ++list;
    }

    return *list != NULL;
}
```

Program output is:

> The Lord of the Rings

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a code based on Apache's WordUtils.capitalize() method. You can set your Delimiters as a Regex String. If you want words like ["and", "but", "of"] to be skipped, just set them as a delimiter.

```
public static String capitalize(String str, final String delimitersRegex) {
    if (str == null || str.length() == 0) {
        return "";
    }

    final Pattern delimPattern;
    if (delimitersRegex == null || delimitersRegex.length() == 0){
        delimPattern = Pattern.compile("\\W");
    }else {
        delimPattern = Pattern.compile(delimitersRegex);
    }

    final Matcher delimMatcher = delimPattern.matcher(str);
    boolean delimiterFound = delimMatcher.find();

    int delimeterStart = -1;
    if (delimiterFound){
        delimeterStart = delimMatcher.start();
    }

    final int strLen = str.length();
    final StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(strLen);

    boolean capitalizeNext = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < strLen; i++) {
        if (delimiterFound && i == delimeterStart) {
            final int endIndex = delimMatcher.end();

            buffer.append( str.substring(i, endIndex) );
            i = endIndex;

            if( (delimiterFound = delimMatcher.find()) ){
                delimeterStart = delimMatcher.start();
            }

            capitalizeNext = true;
        } else {
            final char ch = str.charAt(i);

            if (capitalizeNext) {
                buffer.append(Character.toTitleCase(ch));
                capitalizeNext = false;
            } else {
                buffer.append(ch);
            }
        }
    }
    return buffer.toString();
}
```

Hope that Helps :)